# JQuery: Swipe between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to mock the "swipe between page" feature of iPads using jQuery UI.

I have these two full-screen divs:

```
<div id="introLayer" class="layer"></div>
<div id="gameLayer" class="layer" style="display:none;"></div>
```

At some point, the introLayer must hide sliding to the left, being replaced by the gameLayer, following its slide motion.

I tried the following:

```
    $('#introLayer').hide(
        'slide',
        { direction: "left" },
        1000);

    $('#gameLayer').show(
        'slide',
        { direction: "left" },
        1000);
```

It results in the introLayer sliding out nicely, but the gameLayer only appears afterwards and without any effect.

Comment: maybe if you hide the `gameLayer` first using `$('#gameLayer').hide()` instead of putting `style="display:none;"`

Comment: Have you thought about using jQuery mobile? This is built into that.

Comment: Never used that framework, looking into it right now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the gameLayer first by calling $('#gameLayer').hide() instead of putting it in inline style: `style="display:none;"`

```
$('#gameLayer').hide(); 

$('#introLayer').hide(
  'slide',
    { direction: "left" },
    1000);

$('#gameLayer').show(
    'slide',
    { direction: "left" },
    1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Doesn't help though :( result is the same

Comment: Hey nice jsfiddle... It works out there. I suppose the problem is not code-related anymore.

Comment: yes maybe, did you make sure to use the right UI library along with jQuery?

Comment: just removed everything from my layout, adding only two blank divs. It works that way... Will no add components one by one until I can isolate the issue. Your code is definitely right, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#gameLayer').hide();    
 $('#introLayer').hide(
            'slide',
            { direction: "left" },
            1000 ,  function(){  $('#gameLayer').show(
            'slide',
            { direction: "left" },
            1000);});
```

try like this   or  try below

```
$('#gameLayer').hide(); 

$('#introLayer').hide(
  'slide',
    { direction: "left" },
    1000);

$('#gameLayer').show(
    'slide',
    { direction: "right" },
    1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It's better, but this cause the gameLayer to slide in only once the introLayer has slid out of the screen. They must move together :(

Comment: Yep, that one works in isolation like on Gustonez's jsfiddle. Gotta see what's wrong in my layout ;-)